# how can we take input line by line in command line argument in java

Tags: java

I want to write a command-line argument program in java where the input 
one on each line rather than spaces.
this is how I want to take input as command line argument

```
like 1 then the next input will be at next line of console
```

Comment: That is not how command line arguments work on any platform I know of; **why** do you want that? **How** would you use it?

Comment: bu if we had to do then how we will do it.

Comment: this problem has asked in coding round

Comment: use scanner for input and use sc.nextLine(); for taking input

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String myLine = scan.nextLine();
```

You'll find more information on their implementation in the [API Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for [java.util.Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score -1):

In this example, we are printing all the arguments passed from the command-line. For this purpose, we have traversed the array using for loop.

```
public static void main(String args[]){  

  for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)  {
    System.out.println(args[i]);  
  }
}
```

compile by > javac A.java

run by >

```
java A sonoo \
jaiswal \
1 \
3 \
abc
```

```
Output:sonoo
       jaiswal
       1
       3
       abc
```

For more detail referre https://www.javatpoint.com/command-line-argument